# Error en Laravel Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Hola estoy haciendo una conexion desde laravel a postgres, pero me devuleve este error

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user

cuando hago la conexion por PDO, es exitosa, pero cuando configuro el esquema en laravel, me arroja ese error, alguien me podria ayudar

Comment: En donde seteaste los parámetros de conexión? en el *.env* o en el *database.php*? por favor, mostrá los datos que modificaste. Claramente dice que falló la autenticación.

Answer (score 0):

revisa tu archivo `.env` y verifica tener algo como esto

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]